# Cannot type backtick (`) in PHPStorm and Android Studio (snap)

Tags: java, 22.04

On a fresh Ubuntu 22.04 installation with German keyboard selected in the installation process, I cannot type the backtick (`) in files in Android Studio or PHPStorm.

Both applications were installed using `snap`.

I stumbled upon some old bug reports but nothing recent.

Is there an easy fix for this?

Comment: Dead keys also do not work in for example Libreoffice Writer comment windows.

Comment: Probably I have to disable dead keys? Is that possible using the UI?

Answer (score 0):

It works when choosing "German (no dead keys)". This was a bit hidden in the user interface, you have to press the "+" below input sources and for "German", then the option "German (no dead keys)" shows up.
Make sure to remove the old input method "German" and restart PHPStorm:

[image: Option no dead keys]